# Catching "Why Does...." Opinion-based Questions

Tags: feature-request

I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697903/why-does-yeoman-uses-bower-instead-of-only-npm) and it got me thinking about how to keep questions that are obviously opinion-based from ever getting asked.

In this particular case, the question has a "correct" answer, so I didn't flag it as opinion-based, but in many cases, the use of the "5 W questions"[1] are a strong indicator that there is an opinion based question in the works.  My understanding is that there are filters that flag questions without any code as being probably low quality.  Can a filter be written which looks for questions with any of the 5 W's in the title and no code in the body and pops up a reminder about opinion-based questions or a link to the "How to Ask" page?

EDIT: As noted in comments, "Where" is a SQL keyword (and thus flows into other languages/frameworks, such as Rails).  I would say there are common tokens, "Why does", "Why is", "What was", etc. which indicate that somebody is looking for an opinion.

[1] The 5 W's being "Who, What, Where, When, Why".  "Who" and "When" may not really need filtering out...

Comment: I think "why" is really the only one that's even close to being a strong indicator. All of the others would certainly have too many false positives. WHERE is a keyword in SQL.

Comment: But "Where Is" isn't...

Comment: @ABMagil: [You](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918202/) [think](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683665/where-is-boost-process) [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452851/where-is-sql-server-management-studio-2012)?

Comment: @AmalMurali I'm not saying you can't write a good question with those words in the title.  I'm saying, if you write those words in the title, you might be writing an opinion based question.  In which case, a gentle prompt, especially to low-rep users wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Prompts don't work.  We give plenty of prompts and new users never read them.  And for the few that do, you are going to trigger too many false positives,and new users will be making crazy edits because of the prompt.

Comment: @psubsee2003 How do we know that new users don't read them?  Isn't that just bias?  i.e. if a user reads it and doesn't ask the question, how would you know?  You can only see the failures.

Comment: @ABMagil primarily based on my observations and observations on others on meta (including SE employees).  New users are given many prompts about how to ask questions but thousands of questions are still posted that fail to meet question asking guidelines.

Comment: -1, because adding an impediment to asking a question here based on a poor filter on common words is simply a bad idea, especially when you have no solid foundation for proving that the current way of dealing with those types of questions is ineffective (and you've proven that's the case with your comments to Amal's answer, as I've demonstrated in a comment there). This would negatively impact a large number of questions that are quite appropriate here for a very small percentage that are an actual problem.

Comment: what we really need is to [Add a “Magic 8-Ball” feature to the Ask a Question page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1696/165773)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why do we need another filter? Questions containing these words are not necessarily primarily opinion-based.

For example, consider the following questions. All of these are perfectly on-topic on Stack Overflow.

## Who

- [Who "Killed" my process and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why)
- [Who defines regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257038/who-defines-regular-expressions)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179399/who-uses-docbook
- [Who is Administrator of MySQL schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694335/who-is-administrator-of-mysql-schema)

## What

- [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)
- [What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator)
- [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)
- [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)

## Where

- [Where Is Machine.Config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config)
- [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)
- [Where do the Python unit tests go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151/where-do-the-python-unit-tests-go)
- [Where are iOS 5 simulator screenshots stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286120/where-are-ios-5-simulator-screenshots-stored)

## When

- [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)
- [How to decide when to use Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062614/how-to-decide-when-to-use-node-js)
- [When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this)
- [When to use struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c)

## Why

- [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)
- [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result)
- [Why doesn't GCC optimize a*a*a*a*a*a to (a*a*a)*(a*a*a)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa)
- [Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)

---

> I would say there are common tokens, "Why does", "Why is", "What was", etc. which indicate that somebody is looking for an opinion.

Not always. There could be perfectly legitimate, and on-topic questions whose title may contain one of these tokens. The best way, in my opinion, would be to **close these questions as and when they're discovered**. There's no need for a special filter.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist) sounds solidly opinion-based to me.

Comment: And while not opinion-based, I feel like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179399/who-uses-docbook) would get downvoted and closed if posted today, rather than in '08.

Comment: [Who uses DocBook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179399/who-uses-docbook) doesn't look on-topic to me *at all*. `I was wondering what people use for Documentation... I'm an advocate of LaTeX over Word... I'm inertested to hear from anyone who has successfully convinced their team to use DocBook for documentation?`

Comment: @DavidRobinson: You're missing the point. These are not the only questions on the site that matches the said criteria. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of other similar questions. The main point of the answer is that, **adding a filter or notification won't help achieve anything**. Because users *never* bother to read anything you point them at. If they all read the FAQ and [Ask] before asking, we wouldn't have to do this at all.

Comment: @AmalMurali I think that's where we disagree.  I read the FAQ and I read How To Ask and I read both a couple times and my first question still sucked.  It is REALLY hard to write a good question, by design.  Especially nowadays.  Yes, there are help vampires, who will ignore it.  But there are also just well-intentioned fools, like I was, who need nudges in the right direction.  This is intended to help them.

Comment: @AmalMurali: I agree with that (I disagree with the OP's feature request). But your answer actually states explicitly `All of these are perfectly on-topic on Stack Overflow`. Why say that and then put a link to such an off-topic question?

Comment: @ABMagil: So you found 1 of 16 of the linked questions that "sounds solidly opinion-based". Let's see... That's a 6.25% rate of poor questions that meet your filter, meaning 93.75% of them don't. Sounds like a really bad idea to add a new filter that would remove 93+% of good questions to catch < 7% actual bad questions, based on that sample. I agree we do not need an additional filter on the words you've suggested, and you've helped demonstrate why we don't here. Thanks. :-)